# Can't launch Windows 10 emulator in Visual Studio 2015

Tags: visual-studio-2015, windows-10

Shows up XDE.exe "Failed to load SKU "WP": Unable to load one or more of the requested types. Retrieve the LoaderExceptions property for more information."

Tried to stop and restart Hyper-V from features and re install Windows 10 Emulator.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem. Deleting the Microsoft Android emulator worked for me. Go into system settings and search for "Programs and Features" and delete it from there.

Answer (score 0):

This appears to be an issue with the Microsoft Android emulator - looks like it's trying to load the Android emulator instead of the WP10. Try uninstalling the Android emulator and see if that works

Answer (score 0):

Do you use Windows 10 Professional or Windows 10 Home? The Emulators work with W10 Pro only. Additionally, I needed to buy a full version of w10 Pro (product key) since my W10Pro upgrade pack from W10 Home Upgrade from W8.1 Home did not work.